# Append html element in php like jQuery append

Tags: php

I know jQuery append element, but I want to know is there any way so that I can append 50 similar elements using php with some loop so something else, The elements I want to append 50 times are given here,

```html
<div class='test'>
  <span class='<?php echo $result[0]->cc1;?>'><?php echo $result[0]->dd1;?></span>
</div>
  
<div class='test'>
  <span class='<?php echo $result[0]->cc2;?>'><?php echo $result[0]->dd2;?></span>
</div>
  
<div class='test'>
  <span class='<?php echo $result[0]->cc3;?>'><?php echo $result[0]->dd3;?></span>
</div>
  
<div class='test'>
  <span class='<?php echo $result[0]->cc4;?>'><?php echo $result[0]->dd4;?></span>
</div>
  
//  and so on.. up to 50.
```

Tried this but not working,

```html
<?php for ($i=0; $i <50; $i++) : ?> <span class='<?php echo $result[0]->cc'+i+';?>'><?php echo $result[0]->dd'+i+';?></span> <?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: `<?php for ($i=0; $i <50; $i++) : ?> your html <?php endfor; ?>`

Comment: Sir, I have tried this but it is not working, 

<?php for ($i=0; $i <50; $i++) : ?> <span class='<?php echo $result[0]->cc'+i+';?>'><?php echo $result[0]->dd'+i+';?></span> <?php endfor; ?>

Comment: How is it Not Working. Please be specific

Comment: I am using it in wordpress template.php file. I have pasted exact code but it is not working

Comment: php concatenator is a `.` not a `+`

Comment: and if you want to use the `i` from the loop it will be `$i`

Comment: It is also not working, 
<?php for ($i=0; $i <50; $i++) : ?> <span class='<?php echo $result[0]->cc'.$i.';?>'><?php echo $result[0]->dd'.$i.';?></span> <?php endfor; ?>

Comment: Sir, It would be very appreciated if you you can please write full code of how it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a loop

Then using the `$result[0]->{'cc'.$i}` syntax address all your properties

```
for( $i=1; $i<51; $i++) :
?>
    <div class='test'>
        <span class='<?php echo $result[0]->{'cc'.$i};?>'><?php echo $result[0]->{'dd'.$i};?></span>
    </div>
<?php
endfor;
```